# How can I find all if-statements without an else?

Tags: if-statement, full-text-search, code-search

I've got quite a lot of code in which sometimes if-statements have been written, without a matching else-statement. In some places, this is an issue, because when something fails, the failure is not handled correctly. I want to manually confirm all places an if-without-an-else occurs.

I've tried using regex, but I haven't succeeded in finding a way to match the right bracket, since regex [cannot really handle nested brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses).

The code I want to find looks like this:

```
if( ... ) {

...

}
```

The code I don't want to find, looks like this:

```
if( ... ) {

...

} 
else {

... 

}
```

How can I list all these places, so I can go through them?

Comment: I've asked the same question here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1660815/how-can-i-find-all-if-statements-without-an-else
But I'm not sure where the right place to ask this is, as it is very general.

Comment: Do you use some sort if IDE? If not, you should consider to use one ! 
It gives you highlighting and marks missing else or other wrong synthax. An IDE is like Word, but for programming languages! .

What language do you use ?

Comment: Missing an `else` is not really wrong syntax. I use Visual Studio Code for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, it's not wrong syntax. You are right. I provided you a small script which works as a one time solution for your specific case but it's a bad idea to do it with regex. But it works if some conditions are fullfilled and if you have full control over the text you are parsing!  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed by yourself, generally this has to be done with some sort of parser. With regex it's simply just pain and there are a lot of parser / grammar modules out there.

I created a one time solution script (in nodejs), which uses regex and the number of indents for matching starting to closing `if / else` statements. It works if following conditions are fullfilled:

- The file is properly formatted, a starting `if` has the same numbers of indents as the closing `else`

this works:

```js
if(a) {
   if(b) {
      
   } else { // i have same amount of indents as my matching if, works!
     
   }
}
```

this does NOT work:

```js
if(a) {
    if(b) {
        } else { // i have to many indents.
           
        }
  
}
```

- There cannot be `if` and `else` on the same line ! (should not be ususally..)

Here's the script i came up with, it stores all line numbers with an `if` which does not have an `else`. U can check line numbers and click on a given `if`, then vs code highlights the ending parenthesis and you can add the `else`. It uses lodash but only for flattening results in the end. It's not truely dependent..

```js
import { EOL } from 'os'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { flatten } from 'lodash'

// Import your code file:
const code = fs.readFileSync('code.js').toString()

// Regex for matching lines holding if's..
// if(...)
// if() {
// if
const match_if = /if\s?\([^)]+\)\s+?/

// Regex for matching lines holding else:
// }else
// } else
// else {
// }else{
// ...
const match_else = /(\n|})\s?else({|\s|$)/


// small helper fpr calculating indents for first character appearing..
const calculate_indent = (line: string) => {
    let spaces = 0
    while(line.charAt(spaces) === ' ') {
        spaces++
    }
    return spaces
}

// split up the lines by system operator
const lines = code.split(EOL)
const indexes = []

// iterate all lines.
for(let i =0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const line = lines[i]

    // do not process empty lines..
    if(!line || line.trim().length < 2) {
        continue
    }


    // Match the line against if regex
    const if_match = line.match(match_if)

    // process the match if there is an if found!
    if(if_match && if_match.length > 0) {

        // Count the indents, we need this latere
        // to match any found "else" to the correct if.
        // make sure your code is properly formatted and indent levels are correct!!
        const level = calculate_indent(line)


        // Make sure under given level is an array
        if(Array.isArray(indexes[level]) === false) {
            indexes[level] = []
        }

        // store line number to the given level. 
        // For a human the line number is index + 1
        indexes[level].push(i+1)
    }


    // We check the line for else. Note:
    // The whole function won't work for any if() else combinations on the same line..
    const else_match = line.match(match_else)
    if(else_match && else_match.length > 0) {
        
    
        // count index to identify level for matching the correct if.
        const level = calculate_indent(line)

        if(Array.isArray(indexes[level])) {
            // remove the last stored if. We know it ended here!
            indexes[level].splice(indexes[level].length-1, 1)
        } 

    }

}

console.log('lines:', lines.length)
console.log('results:', indexes)

// flatten / remove empty items / sort
const line_numbers = flatten(indexes).filter(d => !!d).sort((a,b) => a-b)

console.log('final lines:', line_numbers)
```

I tested it with this code:

```js
if(sdf) {

    if(sdf) {
            
    }
}



if(asdf) {

    if(sdfsdf) {


        if(sdfsdf) {

        } else {

        }
    } else {

    }
} else {
    
}


if(asdf) {

    if(sdfsdf) {

    } else {
        if(sdf) {

        }

        if(sdf) {
            
        } else {

        }


        if(sdf) {

        }
    }
}
```

Results => `final lines: [ 2, 4, 29, 34, 45 ]`
You may wanna test a little bit more before using it !
But it should work when the indents are correct. This article is also related and nice to read! => [why you should not use regex to parse tree structures....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)